# XSD choice validation where elements have different parents

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

Is there a way to validate using a choice (or other technique) where you require at least of one 2 values that have different parents.  For example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOC>
    <GROUP1>
        <VAL1>TEST</VAL1>
        <DATE1>20130306</DATE1>
    </GROUP1>
    <GROUP2>
        <VAL2>TEST2</VAL2>
        <DATE2>20130405</DATE2>        
    </GROUP2>
</DOC>
```

How can I validate that this document has at least one of DATE1 and/or DATE2?  i.e. if both DATE1 and DATE2 are blank, the document is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done in XSD 1.0. You have to augment your XSD 1.0 with Schematron, or move to XSD 1.1 (very limited support) and use an assert.

Below is a possible way using XSD 1.1, based on your description (empty values, so I assume DATEx is a mandatory field):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">       
    <xsd:element name="DOC">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="GROUP1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="VAL1" type="xsd:string"/>                        
                            <xsd:element name="DATE1" type="date"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="GROUP2">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="VAL2" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="DATE2" type="date"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>

            <xsd:assert test="string-length(concat(GROUP1/DATE1, GROUP2/DATE2)) gt 0"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:simpleType name="date">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="|[0-9]{8}"/>        
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>       
</xsd:schema>
```